# Can I use the mic with a voice record ? Python

Tags: python, selenium, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

im working in a selenium project and i need use the mic into a website. But I need run an specific voice record into the mic. So when the project is running i need this, 1-Open the website 2-Use the mic into the website 3-The mic listen the voice record and not my voice.

I hope you understand my problem, and apologize for my english, i have a low level.

Comment: Please show us your code trials.

Comment: No. Selenium is used for UI testing - you can click elements, hover over them, upload files, read information from a site, but voice recognition is not part of the Selenium plugin.

Comment: @TalAngel do u know a package who let me do what im looking for ?

Comment: @MartinLackington Sorry, I'm not aware of such a plugin. Yet, surely, Selenium can't do that.